# drawImage() will not display image saved locally, but will display images hosted elsewhere

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas

I've got a Vue app working but have hit a snag. I'm able to use `drawImg` on an image hosted elsewhere, but when saving the file and trying to load locally, it does nothing. No error, it just doesn't draw the image. I'm able to get the same image to load in a normal `img` tag so it isn't a path issue. Below is the code to load the image, both with examples of a saved image and the URL.

```
loadImg() {
    this.img = new Image();

    this.img.onload = () => {
        this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
    }

    //this.img.src = '../../public/body-outline.jpg'; // does nothing
    this.img.src = 'https://www.templatesfront.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/human-body-outline-5641.jpg'; // works just fine
}
```

And for completeness, the entire `.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <div align="center">
            <canvas @mousedown="startPainting" @mouseup="finishedPainting" @mousemove="draw" id="canvas"></canvas>
            <v-btn @click="clear">Clear Area</v-btn>
            <v-btn @click="saveImg">Save</v-btn>
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable */

export default {
    name: 'Canvas',
    components: {},
    data() {
        return {
            painting: false,
            canvas: null,
            ctx: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
    startPainting(e) {
      this.painting = true;
      this.draw(e)
    },
    finishedPainting() {
      this.painting = false;
      this.ctx.beginPath()
    },
    draw(e) {

      if(!this.painting) return

      this.ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            this.ctx.lineCap ="round"

            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,255,255,0.4)';
        this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
        if (this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation !== "multiply")     // use multiply if available
            this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'; // fallback mode

     this.ctx.lineTo(e.layerX,e.layerY)
     this.ctx.stroke()

     this.ctx.beginPath()
         this.ctx.moveTo(e.layerX,e.layerY)
        },
        clear() {
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            this.loadImg();
        },
        saveImg() {
            let dataUrl = this.canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(dataUrl)
        },
        loadImg() {
            this.img = new Image();
            //this.img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

            this.img.onload = () => {
                this.ctx.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0);
            }

            //this.img.src = '../../public/body-outline.jpg';
            this.img.src = 'https://www.templatesfront.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/human-body-outline-5641.jpg'
        }
  },
    mounted() {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        this.loadImg();

        // Resize canvas
        this.canvas.height = 400;
        this.canvas.width = 800;
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

#canvas {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using `require` for the path. You can use the path directly:

```
this.img.src = '/body-outline.jpg';
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand how that works but it does. Thank you.

Comment: You are using `'../../public'` an this route doesnt point anywhere on build, at leat you use require for this route (webpack proccess will process it), but as your image is on public folder, you can call you directy (like the answer).